# Converting a collection to another collection type without predefined method in Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8

What I'm looking for is a way to convert a collection of one type to a collection of another type using **streams** and **map** WITHOUT having a predefined function/functional interface that converts object A to object B. Java 6 example:

```
for (ObjectA objA : collectionA) {
    ObjectB objB = new ObjectB();
    objB.setId(objA.getId());
    collectionB.add(objB);
}
```

I'm looking for something in the lines of:

```
List<ObjectB> collectionB = collectionA.stream().map(objA -> {
    ObjectB objB = new ObjectB();
    objB.setId(objA.getId());
    return objB;
});
```

Which of course doesn't work but you get the gist of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After you do the *mapping*, you have to *collect* the mapped objects:

```
List<ObjectB> collectionB = collectionA.stream().map(objA -> {
    ObjectB objB = new ObjectB();
    objB.setId(objA.getId());
    return objB;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 7):

Your sample code is simply missing the terminal `collect` operation, to collect the elements of the `Stream<ObjectB>` that was returned from your `map` operation into a `List<ObjectB>` :

```
List<ObjectB> collectionB = collectionA.stream().map(objA -> {
    ObjectB objB = new ObjectB();
    objB.setId(objA.getId());
    return objB;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you add to your `ObjectB` class a constructor that accepts a parameter of type `ObjectA` and sets the ID, you can simplify your code :

i.e. in `ObjectB` you add this constructor :

```
public ObjectB (ObjectA objA)
{
    setId(objA.getId());
}
```

And your code becomes :

```
List<ObjectB> collectionB = collectionA.stream()
                                       .map(ObjectB::new)
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

For followers,

```
 incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R 
 exist so that java.util.stream.Stream<R> conforms to   
 java.util.List<org.class.Name>
```

after doing a map conversion, actually meant "you are passing the output of your stream to a method that doesn't take that as a parameter" (the stream map conversion itself is actually working), or you're assigning it to a variable that's of a different type.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly convert it by passing the reference of the first collection to another collection parameterize constructor.

Example:

```
     List<String> ff = new ArrayList<String>();
     ff.add("AA");
     ff.add("AA");
     ff.add("cc");
     ff.add("dd");
     ff.add("ee");

     System.out.println(ff.size());

     HashSet<String> gg = new HashSet<>(ff);

     System.out.println(gg.size());
     for (String s: gg) {
          System.out.println("output= " + s);
    }
```

The size of 5 is decremented to 4 in another collection as List can contains duplicates while Set is not.

Output:

> 5
>
> 4
>
> output = AA
>
> output = cc
>
> output = dd
>
> output = ee